# Python List Multiple Iterations

Tags: python, iteration

If someone would like to iterate through multiple lists with multiple iteration variables how would it be done without using python built in functions like `zip()`, or `list comprehensions`? Some basic functions are allowed like len.

I have tried making this work with this code:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]
list3 = []

def function():
    for i,y in (list1, list2):
        total = i * y
        list3.append(total)
    return list3
print(function())
```

But I get an error

> "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)".

I am trying to get a new list which will multiply the 1st element with the 1st element in the other list and so on.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the functions provided? Have you considered using an index instead (`return list1[i] * list2[i] * list3[i]`)?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `zip()` ? You could go for `for lst in (list1, list2, list3)`.

Comment: Use `zip`; that's (one of the reasons) what it's there for.

Comment: What's the point of having an unconditional `return` in that `for` loop? It's going to return after one iteration, even if you did use `for i,y in zip(list1, list2):`

Comment: Try think of another way to write the for loop using indices. That way you can keep an index incrementing and call list1[index] and list2[index]

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. Accessing through indexes this way hasn't occurred to me. I am sorry because I haven't posted this question more clearly. But I have done what I needed to so thanks to all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your two arrays are `equal by size`. Below answer is right

```
    list1 = [2,2,2]
    list2 = [3,3,3]

    def function():
        for i in range(len(list1)):
            print(list1[i]*list2[i])
    print(function())
```

But best practice is use to `zip` method

```
for i, j in zip(list1, list2):
    print(i * j)
```

Comment: Yes I have done it, thank you very much. Accessing through each index in the list like this hasn't occurred to me. I need to apologize for everyone. I thought I had defined the question clearly and I am still new to programming so I posted something that would puzzle people.

Comment: if my solution sloved your problem, upvote and mark as right answer